# showing all values null in databse while doing with django

Tags: python, django, mysql-workbench

In django when i applied models .py code and save the file its working properly but when user enters the details in the form and when i check the databse its shows null in the rows and just the password appers. Can you help me with the solution. Here's my model.py code

```
class studentinfo(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
   Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
   Email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False, default="")
   Date_of_Birth = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
   Number = models.IntegerField(10, blank=False)
   Password = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

[The database shows every value as null in the row and just the password is appeared in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAbsk.png)

here's my views.py

```
def form(request):
  first_name = request.POST.get('First_Name')
  last_name = request.POST.get('Last_Name')
  date_of_birth = request.POST.get('Date_of_Birth')
  number = request.POST.get('Number')
  email = request.POST.get('Email')
  password = request.POST.get('Password')

  o_ref = studentinfo(First_Name=first_name, Last_Name=last_name, Date_of_Birth=date_of_birth,Number=number,Email=email, Password=password)
o_ref.save()
print("User Created")
return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Comment: Try this `studentinfo.objects.create(First_Name .....)`

Comment: The first step should be to check if your request actually contains anything. It may be null and you're just assigning null values to your model

Comment: Can you show your template containing the form?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, class names should be in `CamelCase`.

Comment: thank you guys got the error and solved, cheers. @Cm0295 . there was a mistake in the template with assigning the names to the fields. Thank you.